# SQLAlchemy IndexError: list index out of range python in raspberry

Tags: python, csv, sqlalchemy

I got error IndexError: list index out of range when I running my program. This is my source code

```
import csv
from sqlalchemy import *

db = create_engine('mysql://root:123@localhost/client')

meta = MetaData(db)
table = Table('DataSensor', meta,
   Column('id',Integer, primary_key=True),
   Column('Tanggal', DateTime),
   Column('Tipe_sensor', String(50)),
   Column('Value', Integer),
   Column('Ket', String(50)))

with open('sensortest.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
     tbl_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
     for row in tbl_reader:
         table.insert().values(id=row[0], Tanggal=row[1], Tipe_sensor=row[2], Value=row[3], Ket=row[4])
conn = db.connect()
```

I want import my database file (txt) . Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for row in tbl_reader:
    table.insert().values(id=row[0], Tanggal=row[1], Tipe_sensor=row[2], Value=row[3], Ket=row[4])
```

Here you are indexing row which might exceed the maximum element in the row.

Try to know the length of the row for example.

```
for row in tbl_reader:
    preint(len(row))
    #or print(row)
```

Then check maximum elements in each row and design your code accordingly.